# cts execution stopped half-way

Tags: android

I am trying to execute 2.2 test suite, until this point it stopped with the following error:

> ......
>
> android.content.res.cts.ResourcesTest#testGetAssets...(pass)
> android.content.res.cts.ResourcesTest#testGetSystem...(pass)
> android.content.res.cts.ResourcesTest#testGetLayout...(pass)
> android.content.res.cts.ResourcesTest#testGetBoolean...(pass)
> android.content.res.cts.ResourcesTest#testgetFraction...(pass)
> android.content.res.cts.ResourcesTest#testParseBundleExtras...(pass)
>
> CTS_INFO >>> Max ADB operations
> reached. Restarting ADB...
>
> CTS_INFO >>> Restarting device ...
> 04:09:28 E/DeviceMonitor: Sending jdwp
> tracking request failed!
> Device(BABABEEFBABABEEF) disconnected
> Test stopped.

I check the result testResult.xml it shows a number of tests not yet executed:

> Tests Passed 652
>
> Tests Failed 10 Tests
>
> Timed out 64
>
> Tests Not Executed 23114

What is the reason the test stopped half way like this?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `maxTestCount` to `0` in your *host_config.xml*, as suggested in [this post](http://androidforums.com/android-lounge/107874-regarding-android-cts-test-device.html#post1871744).

Comment: The above problem is when I ran the test with maxTestCount already set to 0.